# Копировать текст на (Command+c) Mac OS

Tags: html, jquery, clipboard, clipboard.js

Текст не копируется с командой:

```
document.execCommand('copy');
```

Использую  https://clipboardjs.com/ копирует на ура но дело в том что **я хочу при вставленни текста автоматический копировалась как это сделать?.**

(Я делаю очиститель так сказать CTRL + V нажали тутже очищает он +,-,: и.т.д и автоматический копирует)

Answer (score 4):

Во всех браузерах команду копирования можно выполнить только если она была инициирована пользователем. Это сделано специально для того чтобы через JS нельзя было наделать дел, удалив из буфера обмена что-нибудь помимо воли и желания пользователя.

[Проверить что операция копирования разрешена](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/queryCommandEnabled) можно так:

```
if (document.queryCommandEnabled('copy')) {
    // копировать можно, ура!
}
```

Если при ваших исходных данных условие выше не выполняется, то исправить ситуацию можно только изменением исходных данных, то есть логики работы вашей программы - само действие должно быть вызвано пользователем.

Вполне может быть что в вашем браузере в штатных настройках желаемое поведение *в принципе* недостижимо.